# DocuSign Objective C REST API setup

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to set up an Objective C XCode project to test DocuSign API for request a signature via email recipe. These are the steps I've been through now.

1. Downloaded ObjC client
2. Copied code from GitHub (docusign-rest-recipes/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.m)
3. Created a new xcode project with ObjC client and GitHub code.

I now get JSONModel/JSONModel.h file not found.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing through Cocoapods if you're having issues with a manual copy.  There are instructions listed in the README at the root level of the repo:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-objc-client

---

CocoaPods Install

Create a podfile, run pod install, then use the .xcworkspace project file moving forward. To use the clients in this manner, do the following:

At the command line run the following RubyGems command to install cocoapods (note: this might require sudo):

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```

Create a file in your root project directory called Podfile with the following content. Replace the two references to PROJECT below with your unique project name:

```
$ pod 'DocuSignESign', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Run the following command in the same directory as your Podfile:

```
$ pod install
```

**Once you are done installing, close Xcode and open the newly created .xcworkspace project file. Make sure you use this work space going forward!**